# Get line count from Silverlight RichTextBox?

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox, line, line-count

Does anyone of a way to get a line count from a Silverlight `RichTextBox`? I've tried counting the `<Run>` tags but that doesn't seem to be very accurate. The text in the `RichTextBox` will be different each time, so I need a good solid way to calculate how many lines of text are when the user is finished typing.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had this code involving the run tags too (I didn't write it and I can't remember where it was taken from so I won't take any credit for it).  Is it different from yours?

> ```
> int blockCount = 0; 
> int lineCount = 0; 
> foreach (Block b in myRTB.Blocks) 
> { 
>     if (b is Paragraph) 
>     { 
>         p = new Paragraph(); 
>         p = b as Paragraph; 
>         foreach (Run run in p.Inlines) 
>         { 
>             lineCount++; 
>         } 
>         blockCount++; 
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Actually, I hadn't tried that way. But it seems to work pretty well. Thanks!